# Effective and elegant way to get an item from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

For example, i've got an array like this:

```
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        'foo' => 42
    ),
    1 => array(
        'foo' => 143
    ),
    2 => array(
        'foo' => 4
    )
);
```

And i need to get an element with a maximum value in 'foo'. Current code is this:

```
$foos = array_map(function($v) {
    return $v['foo'];
}, $a);
$keys = array_keys($foos, max($foos));
$winner = $a[$keys[0]];
print_r($winner);
```

Which is a scary thing.

Comment: I'd do a `foreach` myself. Way more readable.

Comment: Yeah I definitely agree with using a simple `foreach`. Doubt your array will be millions of lines long

Comment: This is confusing. You're not looking for the "winner" (1, 2 or 3) but for the high-score. Please note the `max()` based solutions will break if you store another item in the subitems because. Which make me wonder why you have this 'foo' key alone (there's no point in having a multidimensional array then)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$input  = array(
  array('foo' => 42),
  array('foo' => 143),
  array('foo' => 4),
);

$output = array_reduce($input, function($a, $b) {
  return $a['foo'] > $b['foo'] ? $a : $b;
});
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => int 143
```

Answer (score 1):

Most elegant?

```
$maxValue = max($a);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

Works even with multi-dimensional:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        'foo' => 42
    ),
    1 => array(
        'foo' => 143
    ),
    2 => array(
        'foo' => 4
    )
);

$maxValue = max($a);
print_r($maxValue["foo"]);
echo $maxValue["foo"];
```

Output with echo `143`.

Output with print_r() `Array ( [foo] => 143 )`

Comment: OP probably needs the index of the item having maximum value.

Comment: -1 because it won't work with multi-dimensional arrays, but some examples in the PHP doc provide work-arounds

Comment: So it doesnt work? Maybe you should test it out yourself ... added some code into the answer.

Comment: Sorry, it could be an error from CodeViper's php set up. Yeah that was the issue. CodeViper uses PHP 5.5 for some reason!. Also I never voted you down.

Comment: Tested again using a PHP 3.10 and it work (http://codepad.viper-7.com/S1dHlp). +1

Comment: Sorry about the confusion but still, it doesn't solve the OP problem. He needs the key assiocated with the max "foo" item, not what's the max value of it. Btw, even if you wanted the max foo value, if you add another key like "bar" in the array and bar is greater than foo, `max()` will of course return the max bar value, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/uxgjHA

Comment: Well, the question is so confusing I've just understood the OP really wants to output `"foo" => 143`, which is the high-score, not the winner. I don't really see the point and the code will break once there's another item along with `foo` in the array (why using a multidimensional one if there's only one key?), let's say `max()` is very elegant but very likely to break in the "real world".

Comment: It was written within a minute, you cant expect such code to be perfect. It could be adjusted to other situations too, but its not necessary in this case. Btw. i just used the multi-dimensional array because the OP used it.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the `foreach` yourself. Readable and easy.

```
$highest_foo = PHP_INT_MIN;
$result = null;
foreach ($a as $key=>$foo) {
    if ($foo['foo'] > $highest_foo) {
       $result = $a[$key];
       $highest_foo = $foo['foo'];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'foo' => 42
    ),
    1 => array(
        'foo' => 143
    ),
    2 => array(
        'foo' => 4
    )
);

$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));

print_r(max($array));//Highest value
print_r($maxs);//Key of hishest value
```